# ZMQ Context was Terminated (Thread)

Tags: c++, c++17, zeromq

Why does ZMQ Context's destructor being called more than once?

```cpp
inline zmq::context_t ctx_proxy(1);

class MyClass {
private:
    // data connections
    zmq::socket_t* sock_frontend;
    zmq::socket_t* sock_backend;

    // utils
    std::thread* t = nullptr;

public:
    MyClass() {
        init();
        connect();
    }

    void init() noexcept {
        sock_frontend = new zmq::socket_t(ctx_proxy, zmq::socket_type::router);
        sock_backend = new zmq::socket_t(ctx_proxy, zmq::socket_type::dealer);
    }

    void connect() {
        sock_frontend->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8880");
        sock_backend->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8888");

        t = new std::thread(&MyClass::proxy, this);
        std::cout << "Thread-ID: " << t->native_handle() << std::endl;
    }

    void proxy() {
        zmq::proxy(static_cast<zmq::socket_ref>(*sock_frontend),
                   static_cast<zmq::socket_ref>(*sock_backend));
    }
};


int main() {
    MyClass();
}
```

When I run it, it shows this error:

```
Thread-ID: 139944261580544
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
  what():  Context was terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: What happens if you try removing the `inline`keyword on the `ctx_proxy` definition? Do you really need it? Is it put in a header file or just in your `.cpp` file? Make the program compileable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you so much! I just removed `inline` and changed my code, now it works fine!

Comment: Lucky guess :-D